# Get and Post Http requests using Google Apps Script

Tags: http, google-apps-script, google-sheets, webforms

I am trying to input `Email` and `Zip Code` in this [webform](https://www.onnit.com/cart/order-tracking.php) and get the results back to the sheet. However the following code snippet does not provide the results:

```
function submitForm() {
  var formUrl = "https://www.onnit.com/cart/order-tracking.php";
  var email = "email@gmail.com";
  var zipcode = "12345";

  // Creating payload data
  var payload = {
    email: email,
    zip: zipcode
  };

  // Setting up options for the POST request
  var options = {
    method: "post",
    payload: payload
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(formUrl, options);
  var resultPageContent = response.getContentText();
  Logger.log(resultPageContent);
}
```

However, when I check the successful request using **inspect element** on web page, this script gets the required data:

```
function fetchOrderTrackingData() {
  var apiUrl = "https://api.onnit.com/orders/7229064/shipments?trackingHash=trtxgT0boZziwMnqfxnAlTf8CqxFqODRhzujdQ0RBl5lHgR52C";

  // Set up options for the GET request
  var options = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {
      "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.107 Mobile Safari/537.36"
    }
  };

  // Send GET request to the API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, options);
  var content = response.getContentText();
  Logger.log(content); 
}
```

I could not find any documentation on this website, So from my understanding (I could be wrong), if we can get `trackingHash` and `order` from **inspect element**, then this can work successfully. Any suggestion or guidance to resolve this is much appreciated.

Comment: I think that in this case, when it can be tested, it might help think of a solution. So, can we test it using a sample value? But, I understand that it is difficult to test your situation. So, even when it cannot be tested, please don't worry.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes you can test it with the following:
`Go to:  https://www.onnit.com/cart/order-tracking.php` and use these values
`Email = kyleistiredhere0@gmail.com` and
`Zip = 59714`

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested it using your provided sample values, I'm worried that the value of `trackingHash` might be created in the internal server side. When the method for retrieving `trackingHash` can be known, your goal can be achieved. But, unfortunately, I cannot still find the method for retrieving `trackingHash`. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. When I could find it, I would like to post it as an answer.

Comment: @Tanaike, thank you for trying. I look forward to your answer.

Comment: I apologize for this question but I would like to ask what are the `results` you want to achieve from the [webform?](https://www.onnit.com/cart/order-tracking.php) I have tried your sample code and the `fetchOrderTrackingData()` function did output some order details.

Comment: Is the `Tracking Number` from the results in `fetchOrderTrackingData()` the one you are looking for?

Comment: yes. That's what I want to get using the function `submitForm`

Comment: I have to apologize for my very very poor skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still find the method for retrieving the value of `trackingHash` from `email` and `zipcode`. But, it seems that the value of `trackingHash` is constant when the same `email` and `zipcode` are used. So, in your situation, how about using your function `fetchOrderTrackingData` by manually retrieving `trackingHash`? But, I think that this is not included in your expected result. So, I deeply apologize for my very very poor skill again.

Comment: thank you for trying, but I found a way. I am posting it as an answer now

Answer (score 1):

```
function getOrderId(email, zipcode) {
  var formData = {
    'email': email,
    'zipcode': zipcode
  }

  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formData
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.onnit.com/cart/order-tracking.php', options);
  var res = response.getContentText();
  try{
  res = res.split("window.orderTrackingContext = ")[1].split("</script>")[0].replace('};', '}')
  res = JSON.parse(res)

  return {
    'orderId': res['orderId'],
    'trackingHash': res['trackingHash']
  } 
}

catch(error){
  return '';
}
  
}


function getTrackingNumber(orderId, trackingHash){
  try{
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://api.onnit.com/orders/${orderId}/shipments?trackingHash=${trackingHash}`);
  res = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  return res['shipments'][0]['tracking_number'];
  }
  catch(error){
    return 'Not Found';
  }
}


function main(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var rows = sheet.getLastRow();
  for(var i=2; i<=rows; i++){
    var email = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue().toString();
    var zipcode = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue().toString();

    if(email == "" || zipcode == "")
      continue;
    
    var orderIds = getOrderId(email, zipcode);
    var tracking_number = getTrackingNumber(orderIds['orderId'], orderIds['trackingHash']);

    sheet.getRange(i, 3).setValue(tracking_number);
  }
}
```

The above script extracts a `TrackingHash` from JSON response and then uses it to get **Tracking Number**, assume that you have `email` and `zipcode` in column A and column B respectively. When you run the `main` function, it will produce **Tracking Number** in column C and it also gives an empty output when `email` and `zipcode` are not yet available for **Tracking Number**.